# Collection and Comparator

Tags: java

I need to place objects User in the collection, and then sort them by  three Comparators.
Thus sorted collection must pass a variable.
What a collection to choose? How to implement it?

```
ArrayList<User> list2 =   Collections.sort(list , new NameComparator());
```

So it is impossible. Can I use TreeSet or ArrayList ?

```
public class User  {
private String name;
private String surname;
private String login;
}

public class NameComparator implements Comparator<User>{

public int compare(User a, User b){

    return a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());
}
}

public class SurnameComparator implements Comparator<User>{

public int compare(User a, User b){

    return a.getSurname().compareTo(b.getSurname());
}
}

public class LoginComparator implements Comparator<User>{

public int compare(User a, User b){

    return a.getLogin().compareTo(b.getLogin());
}
}
```

How to do it?

```
    TreeSet set1= new TreeSet<User>(new NameComparator());

    set1.add(new User("RRRR","TTTT","KK"));
    set1.add(new User("AAA","EEEEE","QQQQ"));
    set1.add(new User("GGGG","BBBBB","ssss"));
    set1.add(new User("BBBB","BBBBF","AAAA"));

    System.out.println(set1);

    TreeSet set2= new TreeSet<User>( new LoginComparator());
    set2=set1;
    System.out.println(set2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ArrayList collection, but elements are not automatically ordered after every insertion (unless you invoke again an explicit sorting). To achieve this you have to use TreeSet (or a ConcurrentSkipListSet).

To use ArrayList you can simply do:

```
ArrayList<User> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(new User());
myList.add(new User());
myList.add(new User());
// Add your elements.

Collections.sort(myList , new LoginComparator());
Collections.sort(myList , new SurnameComparator());
Collections.sort(myList , new NameComparator());
```

Consider also that the method `Collections.sort(...)` **does not** returns a new instance, it's a **void** method. In your first line you were assigning the result of sort to a new ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TreeSet collection. 
While creating the TreeSet just pass the class of the Comparator u want.

For Example: `Set<User> userSet=new TreeSet<User>(new NameComparator());`

This will order your set based on the name.

Comment: then how the same collection to assign another comparator (new SurnameComparator() ) to it then the elements sorted?

Comment: could you please explain clearly? Do you want to sort the sorted Treeset again based on Surname? Yes you can do that too. Creat another Treeset and use the SurnameComparator while creating it. Add the previous userSet to the new TreeSet. If this is not what you asked, please specify clearly what you want.

Comment: TreeSet set1= new TreeSet<User>(new NameComparator());
  
  set1.add(new User("11","3","2"));
  set1.add(new User("5","3","1"));
  set1.add(new User("1","1","5"));
  set1.add(new User("2","1","4"));
  
  System.out.println(set1);
  
  TreeSet set2= new TreeSet<User>( new LoginComparator());
  set2=set1;
  System.out.println(set2);

Comment: TreeSet set1= new TreeSet<User>(new NameComparator());                           For set1 to apply new LoginComparator()

Comment: Yes, I wanted to, as you said. Could you give an example?